# How to reload a JavaFX tableview after inserting new data?

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to JavaFX. I was trying to build a sample college management application, where I have a dashboard(dashboard.fxml) with a table view to fill the student data.

There is a button that loads(newStduent.fxml) the student data input window and stores to the database. I need to automatically reloads the table after the data gets inserted to the table.

Following code handles the  Event inside **Controller.java** that loads another fxml file **newStudent.fxml**, which is handled by **AdmissionController.java**

```
    public void buildData(String SQL)
    {
        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        try {
            ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);
            while(rs.next())
            {
                StudentMaster studentData = new StudentMaster();
                studentData.studentId.set(rs.getInt("student_id"));
                studentData.stdClass.set(rs.getString("student_std"));
                studentData.name.set(rs.getString("student_name"));
                studentData.admNo.set(rs.getString("student_admn_no"));
                studentData.regno.set(rs.getString("student_regno"));
                studentData.stdDiv.set(rs.getString("student_div"));
                data.add(studentData);
                studentTable.setItems(data);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        assert studentTable != null : "fx:id=\"studentTable\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'dashboard.fxml'.";
        assert studID != null : "fx:id=\"studID\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'dashboard.fxml'.";
        assert studReg != null : "fx:id=\"studReg\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'dashboard.fxml'.";
        assert stdAdm != null : "fx:id=\"stdAdm\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'dashboard.fxml'.";
        assert stdName != null : "fx:id=\"stdName\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'dashboard.fxml'.";
        assert stdClass != null : "fx:id=\"stdClass\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'dashboard.fxml'.";
        assert stdDiv != null : "fx:id=\"stdDiv\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'dashboard.fxml'.";

        loadDataToTable();

        DatabaseAccess newConnection = new DatabaseAccess();
        connection = newConnection.startConnection();
        String SQL = "Select * from student";
        buildData(SQL);
        newConnection.shutdown();

    }

    private void loadDataToTable()
    {
        studID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<StudentMaster, Integer>("studentId"));
        studReg.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<StudentMaster, String>("regno"));
        stdName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<StudentMaster, String>("name"));
        stdAdm.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<StudentMaster, String>("admNo"));
        stdClass.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<StudentMaster, String>("stdClass"));
        stdDiv.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<StudentMaster, String>("stdDiv"));
    }

    @FXML
    void createStudent(ActionEvent event)
    {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;
        fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/resources/fxml/newStudent.fxml"));
        try {
            Parent root1 = (Parent)fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
//            stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
            stage.setTitle("New Admission");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void searchBtnClicked(ActionEvent event)
    {
        String name = nameBox.getText();
        String regno = regBox.getText();
        String admno = admBox.getText();
        String stdClass = classBox.getText();

        String SQL = "Select * from student where student_name like '"+name+"%'";
        System.out.println(SQL);
        DatabaseAccess newConnection = new DatabaseAccess();
        connection = newConnection.startConnection();
        buildData(SQL);
        newConnection.shutdown();
        loadDataToTable();
    }

    public void reloadStudentTable()
    {
        loadDataToTable();
    }

}
```

**AdmissionController.java**

The following event handles the data insertion and closes the window, but it does not updates the table view after insertion.

```
@FXML
    void doneBtnClicked(ActionEvent event)
    {
        String name = nameBox.getText();
        String SQLquery = "INSERT INTO student (student_name) VALUES ('"+name+"')";
        ExecuteSQL newQuery = new ExecuteSQL();
        Boolean executeStatus = newQuery.ExecuteSQL(SQLquery);
        System.out.println(executeStatus ? "Data Inserted" : "Error in execution");    


        //        Close the Window after successfully inserted

        Node node = (Node)event.getSource();
        Stage stage = (Stage)node.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }
```

I tried to call the `reloadStudentTable()` method inside the `Controller.java` like this

```
Controller reloadData = new Controller();
reloadData.reloadStudentTable();
```

But it generate some error like this.

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
Data Inserted
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dashboard.Controller.loadDataToTable(Controller.java:132)
    at dashboard.Controller.reloadStudentTable(Controller.java:178)
    at dashboard.AdmissionController.doneBtnClicked(AdmissionController.java:72)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace. Your `loadDataToTable` method only needs to be executed once (from the `initialize()` method: calling it again does nothing new). And once you manipulate the data (e.g. add more items to the list), there is no need to refresh the table, it will update automatically. But without seeing the full stack trace, and you telling us which line is causing the error, no-one can really help.

Comment: @James_D Sorry, I have updated the full stack trace. Hope I will get some help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@FXML`-annotated fields in a controller are initialized by the FXMLLoader when it loads the FMXL. If you create a new controller instance by hand (i.e. `Controller reloadData = new Controller();`), then obviously those fields will not be initialized in that controller instance.

There is no need to call the `reloadStudentTable` method anyway. All it does is configure the columns so they know which data to display; you do not need to do that more than once. All you need to do is add the new student to the table's data list:

```
data.add(new StudentMaster(...));
```

In order to do this, you simply need the `AdmissionController` to have a reference to the data:

```
public class AdmissionController {

    private ObservableList<StudentMaster> data ;

    public void setStudentData(ObservableList<StudentMaster> data) {
        this.data = data ;
    }

    // existing code...

    @FXML
    void doneBtnClicked(ActionEvent event)
    {
        String name = nameBox.getText();
        String SQLquery = "INSERT INTO student (student_name) VALUES ('"+name+"')";
        ExecuteSQL newQuery = new ExecuteSQL();
        boolean executeStatus = newQuery.ExecuteSQL(SQLquery);
        System.out.println(executeStatus ? "Data Inserted" : "Error in execution");    

        if (executeStatus) {
            StudentMaster student = new StudentMaster(...);
            data.add(student);
        }

        //        Close the Window after successfully inserted

        Node node = (Node)event.getSource();
        Stage stage = (Stage)node.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }  

    // ...
}
```

And then in your main controller do:

```
@FXML
void createStudent(ActionEvent event)
{
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;
    fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/resources/fxml/newStudent.fxml"));
    try {
        Parent root1 = (Parent)fxmlLoader.load();

        AdmissionController admissionController = fxmlLoader.getController();
        admissionController.setStudentData(studentTable.getItems());

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.setTitle("New Admission");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you man! I was looking for this for days! Worked like a charm!