# Reload and display blank JavaFX BarChart after launching the program

Tags: javafx, controller, bar-chart, fxml, scene

I'm working on a JavaFX program that can display different grocery items as a BarChart. My code structure uses an initial loading class, **GroceryGrapher.java**, a controller, **GroceryGrapherController.java**, and an .fxml file, **GroceryGrapher.fxml**.

I'm relatively new to JavaFX and I've tried different approaches to creating and displaying my `BarChart`. For the most part I've resolved issues and can load the chart with its data and components, but my issue is that the chart won't display / update after the program has started. The `BarChart` is part of an `AnchorPane` (which all comes under a `StackPane`) in my FXML file, and I've tried to update it after initialization since it starts out blank but it remains blank.

The `BarChart` is part of the `AnchorPane`, which also has a `MenuBar`. My goal was to be able to update different parts of the `BarChart` via the `MenuBar`. When I load the program, the `MenuBar` and empty `BarChart` are loaded:

[image]

This is how I initialize my `BarChart` and its data:

```
public class GroceryGrapherController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();

    @FXML
    private NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();

    @FXML
    private CategoryAxis yAxis = new CategoryAxis();

    @FXML
    private BarChart<Number, String> groceryBarChart;

    @FXML
    //private Stage stage;
    Parent root;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        groceryBarChart = new BarChart<Number, String>(xAxis, yAxis);
        groceryBarChart.setTitle("Horizontal Grocery List");
        xAxis.setLabel("Number");
        xAxis.setTickLabelRotation(90);
        yAxis.setLabel("Grocery Type");

        // Populate BarChart
        XYChart.Series<Number, String> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series1.setName("Chocolates");       
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(25601.34, "Reese"));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(20148.82, "Cadbury"));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(10000, "Mars"));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(35407.15, "Snickers"));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(12000, "Lindt"));      

        XYChart.Series<Number, String> series2 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series2.setName("Vegetables");
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(57401.85, "Cabbage"));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(41941.19, "Lettuce"));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(45263.37, "Tomato"));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(117320.16, "Eggplant"));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(14845.27, "Beetroot"));  

        XYChart.Series<Number, String> series3 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series3.setName("Drinks");
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(45000.65, "Water"));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(44835.76, "Coke"));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(18722.18, "Sprite"));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(17557.31, "Mountain Dew"));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(92633.68, "Beer"));  

        // Need to do this because of a bug with CategoryAxis... manually set categories
        yAxis.setCategories(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Reese", "Cadbury", "Mars", "Snickers", "Lindt", "Cabbage", "Lettuce",
                "Tomato", "Eggplant", "Beetroot", "Water", "Coke", "Sprite", "Mountain Dew", "Beer"));
        groceryBarChart.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
    }
```

Now, I have an item:

[image]

In my `MenuBar` to load the `BarChart` (since it initially appears empty), which utilizes the a method I created, `loadGraph`. I've tried different methods to get my updated `BarChart` to show up with no major success. My initial idea was to use `setScene` in the `loadGraph` method to set the scene to the `BarChart`, as shown in [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/bar-chart.htm).

```
Stage stage = (Stage) anchorPane.getScene().getWindow();
stage.setScene(new Scene(groceryBarChart, 800, 600));
```

While that did work, it naturally replaced the scene to solely consist of the `BarChart`, removing my `MenuBar` and previous GUI:

[image]

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026324/how-to-reload-a-javafx-tableview-after-inserting-new-data) which had a similar issue (I think) but I wasn't really sure how to apply it to my program. I got this code:

```
try {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("GroceryGrapher.fxml"));
    root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
    GroceryGrapherController ggController = fxmlLoader.getController();
} catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I copied over my initialization from the `initialize` method to a new method and tried calling it with `ggController` but it didn't change anything. I also tried creating a new method, `updateData`:

```
@FXML
private void updateData() {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        groceryBarChart.setTitle("Horizontal Grocery List");
    });
}
```

I tried calling it with `ggController` in the `loadGraph` method but my `BarChart` still didn't change.

I know I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not very familiar with the `BarChart` class and JavaFX in too much depth, so I figured I would come here to ask for help. I need to update the existing `BarChart` in my GUI so that my data can load without replacing the entire scene, in order for the `MenuBar` to remain visible in the scene able to perform functions. How would I go about altering the `BarChart` component part of my `AnchorPane`, updating the data as necessary, without completely replacing the scene as I did previously?

Thank you very much and sorry if this question is bad or my coding practices are wrong. All feedback would be much appreciated!

**EDIT**
Just in case it might help, here is my FXML code for the BarChart.

```
<BarChart fx:id="groceryBarChart" layoutY="31.0" prefHeight="566.0" prefWidth="802.0">
          <xAxis>
              <CategoryAxis fx:id="yAxis" side="BOTTOM" />
          </xAxis>
          <yAxis>
              <NumberAxis side="LEFT" fx:id="xAxis" />
          </yAxis>
</BarChart>
```

Comment: The Chart should be updated when it is part of the scene and you chane its data. Are you sure that your `updateDate()` method is called? As I can see it has a @FXML annotation which hints that it's being called when a specific event occurs. Maybe the event doesn't get triggered and your method never gets called? Some simple `System.out.println()` debugging would probably help.

Comment: Hey thank you for your comment, yeah I just made sure it was called. I tried removing the @FXML annotation, I also tried removing the Platform.runLater feature, and the `System.out.println()` line was called each time but the Bar Chart was not updated. I tried with them back in and the same result happened. Here are some images (I pressed the load button twice): https://i.imgur.com/Y7NVbdp.png, https://i.imgur.com/S1TzDLz.png, https://i.imgur.com/3C9tLRx.png, https://i.imgur.com/0G3e5kq.png

Comment: Alright, then it looks like you might be referencing the wrong BarChart object in some way. E.g. it's perhaps not the one that gets added to the scene. Actually it's injected into the controller and added to the scene automatically. Do you instanciate the chart somewhere else? Because then you'd be working on the wrong object. That would also explain why it only works when you replace your old scene completely with a new one containing only the (newly instanciated) bar chart.

Comment: Why are you initializing fields annotated with `@FXML`? They are injected from `fxml` file and must not be initialized manually. You're overwriting them with your own objects and then you modify those new object (which are not shown anywhere, because they're not added to scene graph), so your changes aren't visible. Remove all constructor invocations from `@FXML` fields first.

Comment: Yes of course, it is like I said. Thanks @Guest21, it's actually in the snippet: `groceryBarChart = new BarChart<Number, String>(xAxis, yAxis);` This is the culprit. Don't initialize fields which are anotated with @FXML, as they're automatically injected.

Comment: @Guest21 sorry, I'm not entirely sure what you mean. So I shouldn't be initializing the variables I injected from the `fxml` file, like yAxis and xAxis? I removed the initialization part from the top of my controller class (ie. CategoryAxis yAxis = new CategoryAxis();). I'm still facing the same issue, though. Could you give me an example of what I'm supposed to change?

Comment: @Ignatiamus so I should just remove that line? I did so and I'm now getting this: `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String`. The exception comes from the line `groceryBarChart.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);` according to the stacktrace. What happened now? :(

Comment: Just in case, I included the fxml code as an edit to my original question

Comment: This is a type issue. It expects a string (e.g. label), but gets a double (e.g. value). You should switch the order of your types and your data. First String (labeling), then Number (values), I'd say. It depends on wether you want a horizontal or a vertical bar chart. Have a look at the official tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/bar-chart.htm

Comment: Yeah I read that before I first approached this program. I was basing mine off Example 7-3, the Horizontal Bar Chart, so I used the same order (`<Number, String>`).

Comment: So you said that when instanciating and adding the chart manually, it worked? Because then it could be an issue with your FXML/Scenebuilder setup of the chart.

Comment: Yup, when I had the declaration `groceryBarChart = new BarChart<Number, String>(xAxis, yAxis);` it worked as a standalone graph (ie. not part of my AnchorPane). I provided my FXML code in the question at the end if it helps. Sorry for all the issues by the way I'm just not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: In your fxml file, `xAxis` has id `yAxis`, while `yAxis` has id `xAxis` which is really confusing. And they have the wrong type, too (you inverted ids and axis types). Fix that first (see [this](https://pastebin.com/YwEBbMf8)).

Comment: Oh god, some part of me thought that I would have to invert them because of the nature of my bar chart (being horizontal), but that was actually wrong. Your solution actually made it show up! Although the lines are much lighter than before (if you see the original question's picture): https://i.imgur.com/tLGSKu5.png. It's half unreadable for some reason. Do you know how I can fix this? Also, thank you so much both of you for your help up to this point.

Comment: Ohh, I see. I increased the height and it seems to be thicker, thank you for your comment, that's very interesting behavior from the library. So I shouldn't use the approach I'm using? My program is actually used for inputting grocery lists per month, so should I make the categories months instead and have each month displayed in that style? On another note, it appears I can't edit the existing BarChart's properties despite being displayed. For example, I tried to edit the xAxis' label by using `xAxis.setLabel`, and I know the method is being reached, but nothing gets updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the problems seem to be resolved, so I'll comment on this part only:

> Ohh, I see. I increased the height and it seems to be thicker, thank you for your comment, that's very interesting behavior from the library. So I shouldn't use the approach I'm using?

Well, it depends. There is no other way to treat each data series as a separate list of categories in BarChart (at least, I'm not aware of any), so if you want to have groups of categories, each group with its own color, you'll have to use the same method as in your example.

The alternatives are to write your own implementation of bar chart `layoutPlotChildren()` method which will show only one bar per category (the only one if there are no two data series that contain the same category), or to find another chart library with those features. Of couse, you can always choose to show your data in different format (one data series for each month).

If you plan to use your original method, you'll have to adjust vertical position of bars (to center them again), and you'll have to fix bar height problem too:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class GroceryGrapherController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private NumberAxis xAxis;
    @FXML
    private CategoryAxis yAxis;
    @FXML
    private BarChart<Number, String> groceryBarChart;

    //the height of one bar in the chart (if it can fit category area); you can pick another value
    private final double barHeight = 10;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        groceryBarChart.setTitle("Horizontal Grocery List");
        //there's only one bar per category, so remove the gap (don't edit this, it's used in calculations)
        groceryBarChart.setBarGap(0);
        //gap between categories; you can pick another value
        groceryBarChart.setCategoryGap(5);
        //there're some bugs with the chart layout not updating when this is enabled, so disable it
        groceryBarChart.setAnimated(false);

        xAxis.setLabel("Number");
        xAxis.setTickLabelRotation(90);

        yAxis.setLabel("Grocery Type");
        //if category height changes (ex. when you resize the chart), bar positions and height need to be recalculated
        yAxis.categorySpacingProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                recalculateBarPositionsAndHeight()
        );

        //your original data

        // Populate BarChart
        final XYChart.Series<Number, String> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series1.setName("Chocolates");
        series1.getData().addAll(
                new XYChart.Data<>(25601.34, "Reese"),
                new XYChart.Data<>(20148.82, "Cadbury"),
                new XYChart.Data<>(10000, "Mars"),
                new XYChart.Data<>(35407.15, "Snickers"),
                new XYChart.Data<>(12000, "Lindt")
        );

        final XYChart.Series<Number, String> series2 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series2.setName("Vegetables");
        series2.getData().addAll(
                new XYChart.Data<>(57401.85, "Cabbage"),
                new XYChart.Data<>(41941.19, "Lettuce"),
                new XYChart.Data<>(45263.37, "Tomato"),
                new XYChart.Data<>(117320.16, "Eggplant"),
                new XYChart.Data<>(14845.27, "Beetroot")
        );

        final XYChart.Series<Number, String> series3 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series3.setName("Drinks");
        series3.getData().addAll(
                new XYChart.Data<>(45000.65, "Water"),
                new XYChart.Data<>(44835.76, "Coke"),
                new XYChart.Data<>(18722.18, "Sprite"),
                new XYChart.Data<>(17557.31, "Mountain Dew"),
                new XYChart.Data<>(92633.68, "Beer")
        );

        groceryBarChart.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
    }


    private void recalculateBarPositionsAndHeight() {
        final int seriesCount = groceryBarChart.getData().size();
        final double categoryHeight = yAxis.getCategorySpacing() - groceryBarChart.getCategoryGap();
        final double originalBarHeight = categoryHeight / seriesCount;
        final double barTranslateY = originalBarHeight * (seriesCount - 1) / 2;

        //find the (bar) node associated with each series data and adjust its size and position
        groceryBarChart.getData().forEach(numberStringSeries ->
                numberStringSeries.getData().forEach(numberStringData -> {
                    Node node = numberStringData.getNode();

                    //calculate the vertical scaling of the node, so that its height matches "barHeight"
                    //or maximum height available if it's too big
                    double scaleY = Math.min(barHeight, categoryHeight) / originalBarHeight;
                    node.setScaleY(scaleY);

                    //translate the node vertically to center it around the category label
                    node.setTranslateY(barTranslateY);
                })
        );
    }
}
```

I chose fixed bar height, but you don't need to (in which case you'll have to edit `recalculateBarPositionsAndHeight` method to use `originalBarHeight`).

[image: screenshot]