# JavaFX BarChart how to center-align bars?

Tags: javafx, alignment

I have a barChart : 
[that looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3pPI.png)

The bars align to the left of the category, for instance the "Food/Drinks" orange bar is to the left of the "Food/Drinks" Category text on the X-Axis. 
I want it to be excatly above it.

I tried to play around with .setCategoryBar() and .setBarGap() methods of the BarChart object but those do not achive wanted result no mater what value i pass to them(even negative ones), they only seem to change the thickness of the bar.

FXML code for the BarChart :

```
<center>
  <BarChart BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" fx:id="barChart">
    <xAxis>
      <CategoryAxis label="Category" side="BOTTOM" />
    </xAxis>
    <yAxis>
      <NumberAxis label="Money Spent (PLN)" side="LEFT"/>
    </yAxis>
  </BarChart>
```

Code that binds data with the BarChart :

```
    public void initialize() {
    barChart.setData(DataStorage.getInstance().getChartData());
    barChart.setTitle("Expenses: " + DataStorage.getInstance().getTotalExpenses() + " PLN");
}
```

Comment: Could try something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54575574/6395627

Comment: Note the reason the bars aren't centered is because each `Series` is supposed to represent the same categories but different data. An example would be each `Series` representing a different span of time the data was collected. In your case the chart expects to be drawing 9 bars per category, one for each `Series`.

Comment: Hi thanks for answearing. Tried it, nothing works sadly. Playing around with barChart methods, Series methods different properites etc. But thanks for trying :)

Comment: You might get better help if you [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Having a mock, yet runnable example will make it easier for people to test out possible solutions. If you do post one, please make sure it's _minimal_ — read the MCVE link for more information.

Comment: I found the answear actually :) Posted it as a comment to this post, have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so for anyone who has that problem : use StackedBarChart instead. Transitioning to it takes about 30 seconds.

Read this post if u have mentioned problem :

[Align bars with bar labels in Jfreechart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116867/align-bars-with-bar-labels-in-jfreechart)

Comment: Note that using `StackedBarChart` doesn't fix the underlying issue, mentioned in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19124800/6395627) and [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55301550/javafx-barchart-how-to-center-align-bars?noredirect=1#comment97340549_55301550), which is using series+categories incorrectly. But as JavaFX charts are mainly "read-only" visuals then, assuming your model stays consistent, this is as good a workaround as any.

Comment: Yes but on the other hand there seems to be no way to use series+categories "correctly". Becouse i either get one category and x amount of series of data, or i get missaligned bars as this guy explained stackoverflow.com/a/53742210/11075538 . And honestly it works as intended right now and im happy with it

Comment: And that's really what matters :)